# When I try to open Path from System Environment Variables on Windows 10 it doesn't show in a list format

Tags: windows, environment-variables

When I try to add a new environment variable by clicking on edit button under the system variables path, it is shown in this format.

[image]

[image]

> %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Common
> Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
> Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
> Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin;C:\Program
> Files\nodejs;C:\Users\cundi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\cundi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program
> Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA
> NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
> Corporation\PhysX\Common;%M2_HOME%\bin;

You can see the full Path above.

Earlier, it was showing in this format.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this? It is so frustrating to arrange paths for the environment variables like this.

Comment: Can you provide the full path as text, not an image?  The environment editor seems to detect what a variable contains semicolon-separated paths.  For example `test=a;b;c` brings up the single text edit windows, but `test=c:\windows;a;b;c` brings up the multiwindow.  Something in your path must fail a probe to enable the multiwindow.

Comment: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin;

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\cundi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\cundi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%M2_HOME%\bin;

Comment: I had to split it so that I can post it in here. @MarkTolonen

Comment: You should edit your question with that information instead of a comment, but I can work with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is using some algorithm to decide whether to display the multiline window, and it looks like it uses the first semicolon-delimited string to decide.  A path with certain environment variables doesn't look like a valid path to the algorithm.  My guess is `%USERPROFILE%` is a well-known variable used in paths, or %JAVA_HOME% or %MAVEN_HOME% are invalid or missing in some way (I didn't define them).  Moving the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin` paths to the end of the string made it open properly for me:

[image: multiline window with env paths moved to end of list]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works.
Also, I edit my question like you asked, so that if someone else has the same issue, they can find it in here and understand it better. Thanks for the advice on that too.